# ios - Handle keychain loss after changing to team id prefix

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-extensions, bundle-identifier

As I am developing extensions for my app, to share keychain I got bundle identifier changed to Team Id Prefix.

Now I want to log out user first time as old `keychain` will not be accessible. Problem is I cant upgrade my app.

I installed older version from `appstore` and tried to run from source. It says "App installation failed. The application could not be verified."

Then I tried to install `old developer build` and update it with `new developer build`. This also do not upgrade. It starts installation and then app icon is dull. If clicked it again shows installing.

If I uninstall app and run new Team id app, it works fine.

I want to have run from source to test upgrade and logout user smoothly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the way. You can upload app to `testflight` and test it.

Also could not show a proper message. I use to save app version in app. I wanted to compare old version number and show message. But, after upgrade because of new app id, you cannot access older `nsuserdefault`. So you cannot decide whether it was an upgrade or a fresh install.

So choose to silently log-out user.

Answer (score 0):

**Context:**

I have an explicit AppId with AppPrefix different from my TeamId.

- TeamId: ASJAZSZR
- AppPrefix+AppId: HDJIAZDJ.com.myapp.ios

**To Do:**

I am considering to request the Apple assistance to migrate to my AppPrefix to be the same as my TeamId.

**Question:**

In the technical note they say "A one-time loss in keychain data will occur if you switch your App ID prefix" : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2311/_index.html

I would like to know if the same will happen with User defaults ([NSUserDefaults default]) ? Any experience ?